# Getting the viewmodel in my fragment using 'by viewModels()' is displaying an error

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

When trying to get a reference to the viewModel from the fragment, I get the following error: "Type 'Lazy<TypeVariable(VM)>' has no method 'getValue(LoginTabFragment, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate".
The following image is of my fragment:[image: fragment class]

Comment: Do you have found a solution ? I exactly have the same problem. With all the imports needed

Comment: Yes I did. I followed the instructions on [this link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-39776#focus=Comments-27-4860139.0-0) to manually delete the 'caches' directory in Android studio and it worked. On a PC, the full path could be for example: C:\Users\Jack\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio2021.2. Sorry for not writing the answer for future references.

Comment: Thx for your reply,
To be able to continue, I did this :
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity())[MyViewModel::class.java]

instead of using by activityViewModels()

It works, if someone need a workaround ;)

Answer (score 2):

Check if your LoginViewModel class is extending the ViewModel or not.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. It does extend the ViewModel class.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have already added this dependency to your gradle

```
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragment_version"
```

and according to [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#groovy) the current stable version is 1.3.6

Comment: Thanks you for answering my question. I have that dependency in my gradle file: implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.6'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'

Comment: and also this ```implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:$activity_version"```

Comment: I tried it. Still the same error. The keywords 'apply', 'also', 'with' are also unresolved and the project builds successfully even though these errors are there.